# Top bar Reputation, Winterbash, not updated

Tags: bug, top-bar, winter-bash-2013, achievements-dialog

[image: Top Bar]

I got a +10 earlier for an answer on MSO. I saw the vote on the answer before the +10 appeared, so I knew what it was for.

A couple of times I checked in, studiously not bothering to click on the +10 because I knew what it was.

I recently noticed new activity on the question I'd answered, so had a look. Lo! (it is that time of year) I had five upvotes on the answer.

I also noticed on my SO profile I'd got an extra silver badge. Where's the hat, I wondered? No hat listing on my SO profile at all (I do have a screenprint if needed). From MSO I noticed I had five hats, not my previous three (seems I got Chuck for the MSO comments or answer, or comment on answer, or whatever reason Chuck appears for).

I got the hat total to be listed on my SO profile by clicking on the snowflake in the top bar and clicking `I like hats!`. I didn't have to do that originally (I am ambivalent to hats, so hand't clicked anything).

This is probably information only, as I'm assuming it is to do with the "merging" of an old Unregistered account for a question I answered before I even knew SO existed (it had come up on a google search, and I didn't like the answers given, and I didn't need to register for anything) but of course I didn't get notifications for comments on the old answer (took me some months to work that one out).

The merging therefore must have caused some perturbation with my profile to do with the Winterbash and the rep-notifier. No biggie to me, but someone developer may want to know.

Thanks for the merge anyway. I got my Yearling badge a day early. It now looks like I was an idle `insert desired epithet here` for eight months, but I don't mind :-)

Just as I submitted this, the top bar and my rep-total went up by 10. So now on the top-bar is says +20.

Further information from this morning. Seven hours after being on the site, I arrived, to be greeted by a red `in-tray`. Telling me about a comment from 15 hours ago.

I discovered this on the Winterbash FAQ (no hat for reading that):

```
I'm on Stack Overflow (or on one of a few other sites). Where are my hats?

Users on these sites have to choose to opt-in individually. Just click the "Winter Bash"    popup at the top and click "I love hats!", and you'll be able to earn hats and see other hat-loving users sporting dashing works of millinery.
```

Originally I neither opted-in nor opted-out to `Hats`. I did receive hats. I did receive notifications of hats. After the Merge (speculation as to source of problem) hats did continue to arrive, but notifications didn't. Hats were not even a clickable item on my SO profile until I clicked `I love hats`. Even though I clicked on that, I still receive not notifications although hats continue to cascade in (two today).

I am on SO em Portuguese (I have the hat to prove it) yet I have no ready link to the site (I'm fairly sure I must have done before). When I managed to visit, after a bit of searching to find a method to do so, I found:
[image: Em Portuguese with missing +40]

So, that accounts for the +40, but other things aren't the same, compare with:

[image]

Although looking just now, Em Portuguese now gives me the same drop-down as MSO/SO.

Noticed something unrelated on Em Portuguese, but don't want to post it today to avoid the danger of another hat.

Comment: Hat ambivalence? Profile perturbation? Haha, +1 if for nothing but the vocab used :) To be honest though, I did also notice interesting notification circumstances at times with the hats (I had thought it was by design).

Comment: @TravisJ I have surmised that in this instance the hat-failure is  associated to the merge and that they have obtained, and retained until a remedy was applied, connectivity through the evidence of the necessity for me to effect action to reinstate the exhibition of the hat total on my SO profile. In other cases there may well be the additional hat-related discontinuities you have observed.

Comment: You somehow managed to choose 5 tags, all wrong, lol... (there is a bug in the top bar, not updating winterbash **2013** hats count and achievements box not updated)

Comment: @ShadowWizard far from somehow managing, it was simply expeditious to accept the suggestions the site made to me upon completion of my question. I don't think `bug` is altogether fair. I think I just need a profile-service after the Merge...